# Rounding off values in Java

Tags: java

I have a `double` variable which outputs some values. Examples:

- If value = 62.42, I want to round off the value to 62.
- If value = 62.99, I want to round off the value to 62.

No matter what comes in decimal places, it should only show the whole value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried assigning this decimal value to an integer? like this:

```
int val = value; //where value = 62.42;
```

Answer (score 8):

[Math.floor(double a)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29)
Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) double value that is **less than or equal** to the argument and is equal to a mathematical integer.

Answer (score 3):

The following yields `62` in both cases.

```
public class Round {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println((int)Math.floor(62.99));
        System.out.println((int)Math.floor(62.42));
    }
}
```

Using [`Math.floor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29)

Or you could use `Math.round(Math.floor(double a))`

Answer (score 1):

Cast it as an int. This truncates the double value to integer part, discarding any decimal part of the number.

eg.

```
double d = 1.7;
int i = (int) d; // i = 1
```

Comment: Thgat does not work if the double value is to big to fit into an integer. However when you know that you are only working with small enough numbers this is the easyst way.

Answer (score 0):

```
double doubleRounded = Math.round(doubleWithDecimals);
double doubleFloored = Math.floor(doubleWithDecimals);
```